# GCD function for Assembly in ARM not working propertly

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I am very new to assembly language and I am making a program to calculate the GCD, but I am having trouble. When entering the two numbers it does not returns the correct answer. Any suggestions? I think the problem is in the **gcd** function but I am not sure.

```
.text
.global main


     // Usage of the function: gcd(x,y), with the gcd returned in R0.
     // Parameters: Register R0 must contain x, and register R1 must contain y.
gcd:
     bal mod
     cmp r0, #0
     bne gcd
     // end of gcd function

     // Utility modulus function for you to use in your gcd function:
     // Usage: mod(x,y), returns the modulus of x and y in register R0.
     // Parameters: Register R0 must contain x, and register R1 must contain y.
mod:    push {LR}
    mov R3, R1
    mov R1, #0
    mov R2, #1
    //Shift the denominator left until greater than numerator, then shift back 
_shift_left:
        //R3<<=1; //Denominator shift left
    mov r3, r3, asl #1
        //R2<<=1; //Division shift left
    mov r2, r2, asl #1
        //if(R0>R3)goto _shift_left;//Shift Left until Decrement/Division Greater than Numerator
    cmp r0, r3 // compare r0 to r3
    bgt _shift_left // branch if greater than to _shift_left label
        //R3>>=1; //Shift Denominator right
    mov r3, r3, asr #1
        //R2>>=1; //Shift Division right
    mov r2, r2, asr #1
        //Loop and keep subtracting off the shifted Denominator 
_subtract: //if(R0<R3)goto _done;
    cmp r0, r3 // compare r0 to r3
    blt _done // branch if less than to _done
        //R1+=R2; //Increment division by the increment
    adds r1, r2
        //R0-=R3; //Subtract shifted Denominator with remainder of Numerator
    subs r0, r3 //Shift right until denominator is less than numerator
_shift_right:
        //if(R2==1) goto _subtract;
    cmp r2, #1 // compare r2 to #1
    beq _subtract // branch if equal to _subtract
        //if(R3<=R0)goto _subtract;
    cmp r3, r0 // compare r3 to r0
    ble _subtract // branch if less than or equal to _subtract
        //R2>>=1; //Shift Increment left
    mov r2, r2, asr #1
        //R3>>=1; //Shift Denominator left
    mov r3, r3, asr #1
        //goto _shift_right; //Shift Denominator until less than Numerator
    bal _shift_right
        //goto _subtract; //Keep Looping until the division is complete
    bal _subtract
_done:  pop {PC}
// end of mod function

main:
    push {LR}
    ldr R0, =welcome
    bl printf

    ldr R0, =prompt_a
    bl printf

    ldr R0, =scan_pat
    ldr R1, =a
    bl scanf

    ldr r0, =prompt_b
    bl printf

    ldr r0, =scan_pat
    ldr r1, =b
    bl scanf

    ldr r0, =a
    ldr r0, [r0]
    ldr r1, =b
    ldr r1, [r1]
    bl gcd
    ldr r1, =gcd_result
    str r0, [r1]

    ldr r0, =gcd_msg
    ldr r1, =a
    ldr r1, [r1]
    ldr r2, =b
    ldr r2, [r2]
    ldr r3, =gcd_result
    ldr r3, [r3]
    bl printf

    mov r0, #0
    pop {PC}
// end of main function

.data
welcome: .asciz "Welcome to the GCD Program!\n"
prompt_a: .asciz "Enter a value for A: "
prompt_b: .asciz "Enter a value for B: "
gcd_msg: .asciz "gcd(%d,%d) = %d\n"
scan_pat: .asciz "%d"

a: .word 0
b: .word 0
gcd_result: .word 0
```

Comment: I'd recommend writing the function in a higher-level language and only *then* transforming it to assembly. C is an easy language to compile to assembly manually. Also, learn to use a debugger. Also, I recommend learning about and sticking to the platform calling conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an ARMv7 GCD macro.  You should be able to write it as a function and ignore the .macro directives, etc. I am using GCC directives.

I haven't tested the code in a while so it could contain some error and it may not be efficient for certain cases; nonetheless, it should help you.

```
        1:                                                                                                                                                              

        cmp     r1, r2          // r1 - r2 set cpsr                                                                                                                     
        subgt   r1, r1, r2      // sub if r1 > r2 and put result in r1                                                                                                  
        mov r0, r1                                                                                                                                                      
        sublt   r2, r2, r1      // else sub if r2 < r1 and put result in r2                                                                                             

        bne 1b
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the macro's register args as the scratch regs for the algo?  If the caller wants to save the originals, they can do that, but this way stops you from using it efficiently if you don't need the push/pop part.  (i.e. you'd probably get better results from a C compiler than from using macros this way).

Comment: @PeterCordes - Sorry, I don't understand the point of your comment.  My post was not intended to show the inquirer how to write a macro; just one way to write some Assembly for GCD.  Please clarify.

Comment: Your macro includes `push {r1-r2}` and a matching pop.  It also includes two MOV instructions to put the args in `r1` and `r2`.  Those are also a waste of instructions, compared to just using `\n1` everywhere in your macro where `r1` appears, etc.  (Also, your macro breaks if you use it as `gcd r2, r1`, because the first mov will clobber the 2nd arg).  You'll get better code in the end if you instead just document that the macro clobbers both its inputs, and produces output in a 3rd register arg (instead of hard-coding r0).

Comment: TL:DR If you're going to suggest a macro at all, don't give an example of an inefficient way to design one.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I was not suggesting a macro at all. It was just an example to prime the pump.  I also said that it may not be efficient. Your reply is wise but it's not necessary for this particular post. As you know, efficiency if not the first priority; it's learning.

Comment: If you don't intend to suggest using a macro, then you should definitely not write your answer as one.  It will definitely make some people think it's actually a good way to write asm.  (And yes, SO questions regularly have code worse than that, e.g. saving/restoring registers inside loops instead of using call-preserved regs.  So don't imagine that readers will see the obvious and only take the useful part, if they were already having trouble with writing GCD.)  Writing it as a macro is just noise compared to a comment that says `@ inputs in r1, r2.`  `@ result in r0`